# Convert Oracle Query for Date to MySQL queries

Tags: mysql-5.5, date-format

Need to convert the following oracle queries to MySQL queries.

1)

```
select to_char(to_date(?,'DD-MM-YY')) 
from dual;
```

2)

```
select to_char(next_day(to_date(?,'DD-MM-YY'),'FRIDAY')) 
from dual;
```

3)

```
select to_char(to_date(?,'DD-MM-YY'),'DAY') 
from dual;
```

Comment: Read this: [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). But you need to convert data, too, not only queries. But you need to convert data/table-structure, too, not only queries.

Comment: the oracle to_char function without a second argument (the format string) formats a date value depending on settings on your database server 
and client that are not known to us. to what format do you want the date values be converted?

Comment: The first statement: `to_char(to_date(?,'DD-MM-YY'))` doesn't make sense in Oracle. It converts a string in the format `'DD-MM-YY'` to a "real" date, which is then converted back to some string representation, formatted according to the client's NLS settings. This is a bug waiting to happen, you shouldn't do it like that in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query can be converted to MySQL in two ways.

**First** one is simple query, that adds `interval` of days to compared date, depending on which `dayofweek` it is. It's not the most elegant solution, and different days of week require different values (or selects).
Code below uses `CURDATE` as a starting value, query for each column can be used separately:

```
SELECT
 DATE(CURDATE()) AS now_date,
 DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL (9 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) < 2, (7 + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY) AS next_monday,
 DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL (10 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) < 3, (7 + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY) AS next_tuesday,
 DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL (11 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) < 4, (7 + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY) AS next_wednesday,
 DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL (12 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) < 5, (7 + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY) AS next_thursday,
 DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL (13 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) < 6, (7 + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY) AS next_friday,
 DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL (14 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) < 7, (7 + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())), DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY) AS next_saturday,
 DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL (8 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) DAY) AS next_sunday;
```

Code found and copied from old GizmoLA post's [comment](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/99-finding-next-monday-using-mysql-dates.html#c132093). Similar one, just for Sunday, was explained on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338087/mysql-how-to-get-next-date-of-the-selected-day).

**Second** one is more universal, but requires creating function. In this case it's code could look like this one, found on [SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/next_day) post:

```
CREATE FUNCTION next_day(start_date DATETIME, weekday CHAR(20))
 RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
 DECLARE start DATETIME;
 DECLARE i INT;

 -- Select the next date
 SET start = ADDDATE(start_date, 1);
 SET i = 1;

 days: LOOP
       -- Compare the day names
    IF SUBSTR(DAYNAME(start), 1, 3) = SUBSTR(weekday, 1, 3) THEN    
     LEAVE days;
    END IF;

    -- Select the next date
    SET start = ADDDATE(start, 1);
    SET i = i + 1;

    -- Not valid weekday specified
    IF i > 7 THEN
     SET start = NULL;
     LEAVE days;
    END IF;

 END LOOP days;

 RETURN start;
END;
```

Usage (show next sunday):

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(NOW(), 'Sun');
```

You can also use NEXT_DAY and SUBDATE functions to get the previous date:

```
SELECT SUBDATE(NEXT_DAY(NOW(), 'Sun'), 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding the first command

```
select to_char(to_date(?,'DD-MM-YY')) 
from dual;
```

it can be converted like the following

```
SELECT cast(DATE_FORMAT('?', '%D-%M-%Y')as char) as date;
```

And for the third command

```
select to_char(to_date(?,'DD-MM-YY'),'DAY') 
from dual;
```

it can be converted like the following

```
select cast(dayname((DATE_FORMAT('?','%D-%M-%Y')))as char) as day;
```

but for the second one I could not find a very good conversion.